# Solving a recurrence relation with eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, stochastic-processes

Suppose you are given a recurrence relation describing the gambler's ruin with absorbing states 0 and 100. The probability of winning is given by the recurrence relationship:
$$P_{n}=\frac{1}{2}P_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}P_{n+1}$$ with $P_{0}=0$ and $P_{100}=1$ Is there a way to solve this problem, i.e achieving state 100,  with eigenvalues and matrices?

Answer (score 3):

Write the recurrence as
$$
P_{n+1} = 2P_{n}-P_{n-1}
$$
Then
$$
v_n=\begin{pmatrix} P_{n+1} \\ P_{n} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 2&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} P_{n} \\ P_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}
=Av_{n-1}
$$
and so
$$
v_n = A^n v_0
$$
Now write $A=QJQ^{-1}$ so that $A^n=QJ^nQ^{-1}$. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors enter here.

However, in this particular case it is easy to compute $A^n$ directly:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n
=
\begin{pmatrix} n+1&-n\\n&-(n-1)\end{pmatrix}
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix} P_{n+1} \\ P_{n} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} n+1&-n\\n&-(n-1)\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} P_{1} \\ P_{0} \end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $P_0=0$, we get
$$
P_{n} = nP_1
$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how the boundary conditions tie into this? Moreover, how can I find the $v_{0}$ vector?

Comment: @nipohc88, see my edited answer